# Arduino Yun used as Wi-Fi hotspot

Tags: wifi, arduino-yun, node.js

I use for a project an Arduino Yun with Node.JS + socket.io to provide interactivity between a smartphone, driving through a webpage different devices.

I would like to enable this service for several smartphones at the same time. However I would like to work in the very same conditions that a (well configured) hotspot does:

1. I want to ensure that no user can see the other users on the network,
2. I want to have a limited number of connections on the Yun at the same time,
3. I want to force the different users when connected to the Wi-Fi to be routed to a captive portal on the first connection.

Does anyone know first if it is possible with an Arduino Yun (maybe some actions must be performed on a NodeJS virtual server as point 2). If yes, do you have a tutorial or any clues (do I have to use LuCi)?

Last question, in the same topic, I would like to use a fast granted access using NFC tag emulation to provide Wi-Fi credentials. Has anyone tried this with Arduino Yun and a shield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, here is how I did the job. In short, I separated the two topics of getting a trace of any user using `socket.io` and giving a limitations of the number of users.

First, my Arduino Yun is on a Ethernet network where a router, acting also as the internet gateway, is a dhcp server. My Arduino Yun have a static IP address in the subnet of this router (so it is not a dhclient). This can be set either by modifying the file `/etc/init.d/network`.

Including the lines:

```
config 'interface' 'wan'
        option 'proto' 'static'
        option 'ifname' 'your_interface_name'
        ipaddr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

or by using the LuCi interface.

For more information about the way to properly configure the network in OpenWRT, see [Network configuration](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/network).

Then the router is set to authorize only few IP addresses.

The last step is to bridge the Wi-Fi and the Ethernet (WAN and LAN) keeping the configuration of the Ethernet interface. This can be done using the LuCi interface. Be careful of what interface configuration you keep. [How to setup an OpenWRT router as a Wi-Fi bridge to an Ethernet router](http://root42.blogspot.fr/2014/01/how-to-setup-openwrt-router-as-wifi.html) gives the way to do this.

Note that this can also be done using the Arduino Yun as a DHCP server if you don't want to be connected on a network.

In the end, any connections on the Arduino Wi-Fi will get its IP address in the authorized range (up to 16 users at the same time in my case) by the router/DHCP server through the bridge.

In `socket.io`, I took the id that is given to any connected client and the IP address to ensure that I have a same user.

About the NFC dynamic tag, I developed a NFC specific board with a dynamic tag in the Arduino Yun/Uno format and its library to push through the bridge between ATmega and Atheros any new Wi-Fi code or any webpage. I think it is outside of this scope so if you need anything about this I can give you in PM.

I finally get at the end a device:

- Connected to an existing network and accessing the internet,
- Serving the webpages I want using my node serve,
- Able to push any information on any other devices on the network through my nodeJS server,
- Enabling access to people to local or network content,
- Serving some specific local information through the NFC shield.